# How do I bind '<Return>' to focused (tabbed) button in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have multiple buttons in my tkinter 8.5 GUI (on Windows 7). I want whatever button is focused on (tabbed over) to be selected when the user hits Enter. I know I have to bind `'<Return>'`, but I need the rest of the gaps filled in.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want this to be universal to all applications in the root window you could do something similar to this.

```
def clickButton():
    widget = root.focus_get()
    if widget != root:
        widget.invoke()

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.bind("<Return>", clickButton)
root.mainloop()
```

That will run any command associated with the currently tabbed selection. If you want to limit it to certain buttons you can do type-checking inside of the method. Widget will be whatever widget is currently in focus via the tabbed selection. Also beware of a user hitting enter on certain widgets that may not support the invoke method.

Comment: That was great, thank you. Thanks for the additional tips as well.

Comment: I know this is old, but I do want to point out that with Python3, you need to add `event` as an argument to the function you want to _bind_. So it will look like `clickButton(event)`.